# How to stop code running when if statement is not fulfilled

Tags: python

I am doing a school project and what i want to add is a line of code that would stop the code from running if age < 15 or if age > 100
I tried break but it would continue to the next line.

```
while True:
    try:

        age = int(input("How old are you? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid age!")

        continue
    if age < 15:
        print("sorry you are too young to enter the store!")
        break
    if age > 100:
        print("Please come back in the next life") 
        break
    else:
        break

    print("")
    print("Welcome to Jim's Computer Store", name)
    print("") while True:                                    
    try:
       cash = int(input("How much cash do you currently have? $"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid value! ")

        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: does the `while True:` have no indentation or 1 indent (or 4 spaces, or 8 spaces)

Comment: also, the code provides different results than what is said in this post. all of the code just stops at the `else` statement?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to terminate your script if the first two conditions aren't met in your while loop. In that case just use `exit()` or `sys.exit()` instead of the `break` in those `if` statements

Comment: The placement of your `if else` statements don't really make sense. They make sense inside the `try` block rather than the `except` block. Also, please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to proceed step by step. The code in the question is too long for the purpose. When the first step behaves like you want, you can do another step.

Is is this working like you want ?

```py
name = "John"
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input("How old are you? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid age!")
        continue
    break
# Here, we can assume that 'age' is an integer
if age < 15:
    print("sorry you are too young to enter the store!")
    exit()
if age > 100:
    print("Please come back in the next life") 
    exit()
print("")
print("Welcome to Jim's Computer Store", name)
# When the code above will be validated, the next step will be easy
```

The `while` loop is to assure that `age` is an integer when he breaks the loop (if `age` is not an integer, the program will execute the `continue` instruction and go back to the start of the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a `exit()` after the `if` condition will do the job.

An example would be:

```
x = 5
if x < 2:
    print "It works"
else:
    exit()
```

Or without the else statement:

```
x = 5
if x < 2:
    print "It works"
exit()
```